# "fixated" negetive or positive conotation

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does telling someone "he is fixated on something" have a negative or positive connotation or it depends on the context? for example,

> You are very fixated on your own research.

thanks

Comment: Actually it depends. But your example shows positive side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on context. For example:

> You are very **fixated** on your own research, **but** you need to work on the group project too.

In this case it would be considered negative or at least distracting.

But

> You are very **fixated** on your own research, which demonstrates your willingness **to succeed**.

would be considered positive.

It depends on the focus (a good synonym) and the reason behind it.